# firefox add-on innerHTML not allowed, DOM help needed

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

I'm writing my first firefox add-on.
It was completed, but mozilla rejected it with this answer:

1)  Your add-on creates DOM nodes from HTML strings containing potentially unsanitized data, by assigning to innerHTML or through similar means. Aside from being inefficient, this is a major security risk. For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion. Here are some examples where you do this: (cut...)

I wrote:

```
var myDiv = content.document.getElementById("myContent");
myDiv.innerHTML = "some html code";
```

now I'm not a JS programmer and I don't understand how to go on.
I tested some code like this:

```
var NewNode = content.document.createElement("span");
NewNode.appendChild(content.document.createTextNode("Hello World!"));                   

//content.document.body.appendChild(NewNode);//ok, works
content.document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(NewNode);//doesn't work
```

but it doesn't work until I append it to .body

Samples working on other pages seems not working here. Moreover I don't understand if it fixes the problem that mozilla indicated.

Could you please help me with the code that should replace the two lines I wrote?
If you need the full code, here it is: http://www.maipiusenza.com/LDV/down/ldvgenerator.xpi

Thanks!
Nadia

Comment: It seems you run both your 2 last lines together? it means your are appending NewNode to 2 different parent. remove the `content.document.body.appendChild(NewNode);` then check it again.

Comment: no I tried fist with body, and it works, than commented it and used the second line, and doesn't work. (i fixed the text above)

Comment: Have you checked if `content.document.getElementById("myContent")` actually returns what you expect?

Comment: Yes it works, I have an ".innerHTML" on it and it works fine, but I can't use .innerHTML

Comment: @Nadia: I managed to find a way for your solution, the next one is on the process, check it out, and let me know of the result.

Comment: @Nadia: the second solution is also ready to use, if I were you I would try both.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a quick js fiddle, I was wondering why you have used content.document so I amended it to document and it worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/eDW82/

```
var NewNode = document.createElement("span");
NewNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello World"));
document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(NewNode);
```

I had a similar problem with unsanitized HTML and as I used it extensively I opted to use jQuery which will pass mozillas rules. It makes life a lot easier to be able to create your nodes that way.

```
$("<div>", {id:"example"}).text("Hello World")
```

It just reads so much nicer.

Comment: I used content.document as it is in a firefox extension, if I call document I get a "null" result on getElementById. jQuery can't be called in the extension

Comment: I used the addon sdk, which allows all those things. Maybe you need to just add 'content.' to the last line where you append the NewNode.

Comment: the "content" was just a reporting error, as written below, it doesn't work anyway. About addon sdk, i'm not a JS programmer, I don't know neither ow to start with it. I just found a very simple addon example and modified it to do what I needed. It works, but mozilla doesn't allow me to use innerHtml

Comment: yes, it is for ebay.it users, I saved a test page, you can find it here: http://www.maipiusenza.com/LDV/test/test.htm if you add in the js file, on the two lines where you find myPage.indexOf(".ebay.it/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?EditSalesRecord&")>-1 this:   || myPage.indexOf("maipiusenza.com/LDV/test/test.htm")>-1 it will work on this page too, (you'll see a flash box before the buyer details)

Answer (score 0):

OK then, I did some digging and I think I managed to find your problem:

Whenever you want to inject any kind of html to your extension, The browser considers it as a security hole, that's why you have this problem. you have 2 different solution;

**first:** you can create an iframe and use it to show your html (in javascript whenever we want to show a file we have 2 option, first pass a file path on the server, or use `data:` to show your data directly):

```
var htmlStr = "<span>Hello World!</span>";
var frm = content.document.createElement("iframe");
content.document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(frm); 
frm.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(htmlStr);
```

**second:** this solution would help you out, if you don't want to use an iframe to show your html.

```
var htmlStr = "<span>Hello World!</span>";
var frm = document.createElement("iframe");
frm.style.display="none";
document.body.appendChild(frm);

var win = frm.contentWindow;
var frmrange = win.document.createRange();
// make the parent of the first div in the document becomes the context node
frmrange.selectNode(win.document.firstChild);
var frg = frmrange.createContextualFragment(htmlStr);
content.document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(frg);
```

---

**Old Guess:** the problem in your code is different `document` objects, try this:

```
var NewNode = content.document.createElement("span");
NewNode.appendChild(content.document.createTextNode("Hello World!"));

content.document.getElementById("myContent").appendChild(NewNode);
```

this was my first clue to point out.

Comment: Sorry, my mistale in reporting the code (as I made a lot attemprs). I used your code too (i'll correct mine in the question), and it gives no error, but there is no content added in the page. If I test the same script in a normal html page, it works. It doesn't in the firefox extension.

Comment: No way :-( 
first solution: no error but no output at all.
Second solution: if I use it without changes I get an "undefined where you use document instead of content.document; if I replace it, no error but no output.

About the first clue, it was just an error reporting the code, I used always content.document, but no results at all.

On a normal page all works fine, but in the add.on that code doesn't work

Comment: @Nadia: I just did the same thing with both solutions, created a simple firefox add-on installed it on my firefox, and I got result. could you send me your code or the xpi file?

Comment: the link is in the question, here it again  http://www.maipiusenza.com/LDV/down/ldvgenerator.xpi otherwise could you please send me your xpi and I'll ry to modify it. As you can see my code is very simple.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: hi, di you found any solution? Thanks

Comment: @Nadia: hi again, actually I have installed it in my FF but i don't know how to test it.

Comment: I wrote this comment to the wrong answer (below) here it is again (how to test it)
yes, it is for ebay.it users, I saved a test page, you can find it here: maipiusenza.com/LDV/test/test.htm if you add in the js file, on the two lines where you find myPage.indexOf(".ebay.it/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?EditSalesRecord&")>-1 this: || myPage.indexOf("maipiusenza.com/LDV/test/test.htm")>-1 it will work on this page too, (you'll see a flash box before the buyer details)